# eventBus does not remove previous message in vue2.js

Tags: vue.js

I have created a form which sends the submitted data to the parent by means of an eventbus. However when I complete the form for a second time, two messages get sent to the parent and for every new form completion, the message amount increases by one. Therefore, completing the form the 10th time, will send 10 messages to the eventbus. The submit is implemented as follows:

**Form**

```
...
        <button @click.prevent="onSubmit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
  import EventBus from '../../../config/EventBus';

  export default {
      ....
      methods: {
          onSubmit() {
              EventBus.$emit('submit', this.category);
          },
      },
  };
</script>
```

**ParentComponent**

```
<script>
  import EventBus from '../../../config/EventBus';

  export default {
      ...
      created() {
          EventBus.$on('submit', data => this.submit(data));
      },
      methods: {
          submit(category) {
              this.saveCategory(category);
              this.$router.push('/categories');
          },
      },
  };
</script>
```

I can't see what I am missing as I presume that an event bus does not keep messages on the stack.

Comment: What this event, into `created()` hook, is doing ?

Comment: How do you mean? The created() hook serves to setup the event bus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy solution to get a global eventbus ( and it seems like you want that ) is to do the following before adding your components.

```
var EventBus = new Vue();
Vue.prototype.$bus = EventBus;
```

Then you add components to your Vue for example

```
Vue.component('my-component', require('./MyComponent.vue');
```

Every Vue component has access to the $bus so you can easily just call

```
created: function() {
   this.$bus.$on('event', function () { ... });
}
```

Or

```
this.$bus.$emit('event', data);
```

Here a full example of my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Add am Event Bus
 */
var bus = new Vue();
Vue.prototype.$bus = bus;

/**
 * Add Components
 */
Vue.component('fv-prompt', require('./components/Prompt.vue'));

/**
 * Add an error handler to the Vue prototype.
 */
Vue.prototype._onError = function(error) {
    Vue.prototype.$bus.$emit('error', error);
};


/**
 * Create and mount the vue instance.
 */
const app = new Vue().$mount('#app');
```

Where bootstrap is

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.Vue = require('vue');

require('vue-resource');

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);
    request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, I think that the reload of my categories, triggered the import EventBus again and caused the bus to be defined multiple times.